# TimeSpan vs Duration

Tags: c#, time

After reading the MSDN pages for the `Timespan` struct and the `Duration` struct,
I must admit that I am still not sure what is the difference between them.

Furthermore, the Duration struct contains a `Duration(TimeSpan)` Ctor,
which makes them even more similar.

So can anyone please tell me when each of them should be used?

**Timespan struct:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

**Duration struct:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.duration.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want to use `TimeSpan`.

`TimeSpan` is a generic data structure in the `System` namespace. `Duration` is a specialized structure for WPF animations. The description of [Duration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.duration(v=vs.110).aspx) sums it up pretty well:

> Represents the duration of time that a [Timeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline(v=vs.110).aspx) is active.

If you want to do exactly that (define the duration of a WPF animation timeline), use `Duration`. Otherwise, use `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Very nice.. The namespaces indeed uncover the answer.. Thank you